# load a movie clip from library into the stage using AS 2

Tags: movie, clip

how can i load a movie clip using AS2 from library into my stage. and how to unload it. could u help me ? i appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

In the library, you must to assign a Linkage (right click on th mc) and chech Export for Actionscript and set a name (for example myMovieClip). That name will be used by attachMovie method:

```
this.attachMovie('myMovieClip', 'myMovieClipNewName', depth);
```

and for remove;

```
this.removeMovieClip('myMovieClipNewName');
```

chaus

Answer (score -1):

```
depth = 1;
while(depth<100){
this.attachMovie('bullet','bullet' + depth,depth);
this["bullet" + depth]._x = random(550);
this["bullet" + depth]._y = random(400);
depth++;}
```

//to create 100 bullets randomly on the screen